# Rails Shoulda Matcher - Issue with testing Modularized Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using RSpec and Shoulda-Matchers to test my model.

I understand how to test if the models are like this

```
class Headquarter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :branches
end

class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :headquarter
end
```

And I can write a shoulda-matcher like so:

```
RSpec.describe Headquarter, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(branches)}
end

RSpec.describe Branch, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:headquarter)}
end
```

---

#### My issue

But the problem arise when I am using **modularized** model, take for example `Company::Headquarter` and `Company::Branch`

I tried using this code:

```
RSpec.describe Company::Headquarter, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(:company_branches)}
end
```

But it is giving me an error, which seems like it does not recognize the model as being modularized.

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:company_branches)}
   Expected Company::Headquarter to have a has_many association called company_branches (Company::Branch does not have a headquarter_id foreign key.)
```

Notice the `headquarter_id` in the error, when I am **expecting** `company_headquarter_id`. That is why it does not recognized the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking the code documentation, I found two useful snippet:

### For custom class_name

```
  # ##### class_name
  #
  # Use `class_name` to test usage of the `:class_name` option. This
  # asserts that the model you're referring to actually exists.
  #
  #     class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  #       has_many :hopes, class_name: 'Dream'
  #     end
  #
  #     # RSpec
  #     RSpec.describe Person, type: :model do
  #       it { should have_many(:hopes).class_name('Dream') }
  #     end
  #
  #     # Minitest (Shoulda)
  #     class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  #       should have_many(:hopes).class_name('Dream')
  #     end
```

### And for custom foreign key:

```
  # ##### with_foreign_key
  #
  # Use `with_foreign_key` to test usage of the `:foreign_key` option.
  #
  #     class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  #       has_many :worries, foreign_key: 'worrier_id'
  #     end
  #
  #     # RSpec
  #     RSpec.describe Person, type: :model do
  #       it { should have_many(:worries).with_foreign_key('worrier_id') }
  #     end
  #
  #     # Minitest (Shoulda)
  #     class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  #       should have_many(:worries).with_foreign_key('worrier_id')
  #     end
```

---

### How to solve

#### Models

In case you have models as mentioned in question:

`Company::Headquarter`, add **foreign_key**  tag

```
class Company::Headquarter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_branches, :class_name => 'Company::Branch', foreign_key: 'company_headquarter_id'

end
```

`Company::Branch`

```
class Company::Branch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company_headquarter, :class_name => 'Company::Headquarter'
end
```

#### For the RSpec

`headquarter_spec.rb`, notice **class_name** and **with_foreign_key** function.

```
RSpec.describe Company::Headquarter, type: :model do
  it { should have_many(:company_branches).class_name('Company::Branch').with_foreign_key('company_headquarter_id')}
end
```

---

Source: [Shoulda-Matchers, association matcher Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb)